# Orthogonality and Inverse of DFT Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, discrete-mathematics, fourier-transform, orthogonality

Since there are missing information about my question, I re-open the topic. I am trying to proof that the DFT matrix is orthogonal but i stucked. I just know to proof the orthogonality of two vectors, not a single matrix. How can we proof that the DFT matrix is orthogonal? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Hello :) The matrix $\mathbf D_N$ isn't orthogonal.

Comment: How sir? All books say that the DFT matrix is orthogonal.

Comment: assuming you've dealt with re-scaling issues, the DFT matrix in general is **unitary not orthogonal**

Answer (score 0):

Notation I'm using is the one used [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix).

I'm not assuming that the entries of the matrix are properly normalized :

Let's called the matrix $\Omega_n$. The matrix is symmetric since $\omega_n^{ij} = \omega_n^{ji}$. To prove the fact about orthogonality on the columns of the matrix we have to show that the product between the $i$-th row of $\Omega_n^H$ and the $j$-th column of $\Omega_n$ is $0$ if $i \ne j$ and $n$ if $i=j$, i.e $$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \bar{\omega_n}^{ik}\omega_n^{jk} = \begin{cases}n & i = j \\ 0 & i \ne j \end{cases}$$

The sum reduces to $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\omega_n^{rk}$ where $r = j-i$. So the thesis follows from :

> Lemma : $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} \omega_n^{ki} = \begin{cases} n & k
>  \equiv 0 \hspace{0.1cm} \text{mod} \hspace{0.1cm} n \\ 0 & k
>  \not\equiv 0 \hspace{0.1cm} \text{mod} \hspace{0.1cm} n \end{cases}$

Comment: So which expression say that the matrix is orthogonal sir? I searched for it and the matrix is said to be orthogonal if the inverse of this matrix and the transpose of this matrix is equal. The problem is I can not calculate the inverse of it.

Comment: We proved that $\Omega_n \Omega_n^H = nI$. So for example you're saying that $\Omega_n^{-1} = \frac{1}{n} \Omega_n^H$.

Comment: Thanks sir, from the comment above, "Jochen" said that this matrix is not orthogonal. Is it true?